# How can I achieve google-style table views with UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and I'd like to use it for a "card" like interface where users can scroll for content thumbnails. Basically like 10 pts on all sides of the cell. This will require some overriding of `UITableView`. Keep in mind I'm using prototype cells in the storyboard so I'd like to storyboard a much as possible.

1. I need to get a transparent background and a fill for the cells
2. I need to get a border on the top, bottom, and sides

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @A Tyshka Have you given it a try? If yes, show code.  I am sure Stack Overflow will not write down code for you, but indeed help you out with the point your stuck.

Comment: I’m not expecting code to be written for me, I’m just stuck as to what properties I should be changing. I’ve pored over the UITableView documentation and I can’t find any properties / methods that would seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question. There are multiple ways this can be achieved. I'll just highlight what I did in my last app.

- Subclass `UITableViewCell` along with a `xib`. Using a `xib`, or designing in `storyboard` is entirely upto you. I use a dedicated nib so as to keep the cells reusable in case they're needed in other `tableView`s.
- Set background of cell, and `conentView` to `clearColor`.
- Added a `UIView` (called it `internalContentView` in it's outlet) inside the `contentView` with layout constraints on all 4 sides.
- Set the background color of `internalContentView` as per my design.

Further, I added code in `setHighlighted:` and `setSelected:` to override selection and highlighting behaviour. Since `internalContentView` is a `UIView`, it can easily be customised for corner radii, borders, etc (advised to do so in `awakeFromNib`)

[image]